# Why does hotkey just randomly stop working?

Tags: macros, autohotkey

I use it for 4 keys while playing World Of Warcraft. It runs exactly as it should most of the time but now and then it just acts up and will NOT run consistently. I have upgraded to 2.02 or whatever the latest is and it still fails. When it fails, I can reload the script and it will work until I change zones then it stops again. But then without changing ANYTHING, it will start working again and be good for a few weeks. Its driving me INSANE!!! This is the script I am using and it has worked for a LONG time. The other 3 scripts are identical except the keyboard key is different. IE: 1,2,3,4... Any ideas why it is so random?

```
#IfWinActive, World of Warcraft ;; enabled only in WoW

$1::
While GetKeyState("1", "P") {
Send, {Blind}1  ;; blind mode to send modifiers
Sleep, 250
}
return
```

I've deleted and reinstalled AHK and even wiped my drive completely and started from scratch. Everything is up to date, but I am still on Windows 10 if that makes any difference. I can't update to 11 unless I get a new computer and that won't be for a long time because I am disabled which is why I use AHK and macros to play. AHK has made a HUGE difference and I just want it to be consistent.

Comment: `Process, Priority,, H` `SetBatchLines -1` `#KeyHistory 0` `ListLines Off` , improve the performance and the speed of the script. You can also [exclude](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26) Autohotkey.exe  and your game from Windows Defender, if you trust them.

Comment: What does "until I change zones" mean? (I don't play WoW).  Can you experiment with removing the `WinActive` check?? I could just about suspect some weird hack deep in WoW might be creating another window that gets focus but passes events through to the game engine.

Comment: That line is to keep it from working in every other program. The key coding is used by hundreds of thousands of users and is basically designed to rapidly press the 1 key repeatedly.